# phpMyAdmin Root Account not enough privilege to view users

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb, debian

I login as root in phpMyAdmin, when I on the "`User Account`" tab, it shows " `Not enough privilege to view users.`" I run "`SHOW GRANT`", it shows I have all the privilege. Anywhere I could have done wrong? I've tried to google, but can't find any solution.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall phpMyAdmin / update to 5.1.0 nothing has solved.

> OS: Debian 10 Buster
>
> Mariadb: 10.5.9
>
> phpMyAdmin: 5.0.4

[phpMyAdmin error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZYUe.png)

[SHOW GRANT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjel2.png)

Comment: have you restarted the server since running these cmds? Also - why `no database selected`?

Comment: Yes, restart several times, "no database selected" just because I haven't selected any database yet, nothing change.